# How to get 640x480 Resolution using 12.04 and Intel card

Tags: 12.04, wine, resolution

I have a computer with an intel card and I am trying to play StarCraft.

The only resolution I have is 1280x800 and I can't get it into 640x480 in order to make the game full screen. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you can...  however, making starcraft run at 1280x800 might be an easier choice.

[High Res Patch for Starcraft](http://www.neoseeker.com/news/11951-starcraft-goes-hi-res-with-resolution-expander/)